# shell script Grep -f in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

need help for grep -f to run in for loop

basically for each entry in name.txt, I want to grep all the line(s) from A.txt and write out for in separate files

For example
1) name.txt is a list of three following names

```
America
Europe   
Asia
```

2) A.txt is(tab delimited)

```
X y Z America
x a b Asia
y b c America
a b c Europe
x y z Europe
a b c America
```

now taking each entry from name.txt file, search the corresponding line(s) in A.txt and return in three separate output files:

```
file1: X y Z America
       y b c America
       a b c America

file2: a b c Europe
       x y z Europe
file3: x a b Asia
```

may be writing it in script and execute with bash?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

Run the following script (as ./script.sh name.txt input.txt) where name.txt has the names and input.txt is your input file. the output files are saved as file_America.txt, file_Asia.txt and file_Europe.txt

```
#!/bin/bash -x

while read line; do
#skip empty line
[ -z "$line" ] && continue;
#run grep and save the output
grep "$line" "$2" > file_$line.txt;
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Use input redirection: `while read line; do ...; done < "$1"`

Comment: @chepner: Or `< $1 while read line; do ...; done`. Yes, the redirection can go before the command, and in this case it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '
    ## Process first file of arguments. Save data in an array, the name as
    ## key, and the number of the output file to write as value.
    FNR == NR {
        name[ $1 ] = FNR;
        next;
    }

    ## Process second file of arguments. Check last field of the line in the 
    ## array and print to file matched by the value.
    FNR < NR {
        print $0 > sprintf( "%s%d", "file", name[ $NF ] );
    }
' name.txt A.txt
```

Check output files:

```
head file[123]
```

With following result:

```
==> file1 <==
X y Z America
y b c America
a b c America

==> file2 <==
a b c Europe
x y z Europe

==> file3 <==
x a b Asia
```